# Is it possible to produce .o files with a compiler and then link them using another compiler?

Tags: iphone, compilation, linker, prolog, gnu

For being more specific, I'm wondering if it's possible to compile a .c and a .pl with the gnu prolog compiler but link them with Apple LLVM compiler along with the rest of an iOS project for being able to use prolog in an iOS app.

Comment: You actually link .o files with a linker, not a compiler, so yes it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you link files, you do that using a linker, not a compiler. Some times the compilers call the linker for you so you don't have to do that, that is why you think that the compilers are doing the linking.

This is how you link some object files together:

```
ld -o myprogram program.o program1.o ...
```

For more information on `ld` look [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ld).

**EDIT:** If you are going to use your prolog .o files in an iOS project, you must be sure that you compile your prolog code for the same plattform as the iOS is running on, let's say ARM.

Comment: Thank you! I tried and succeeded, but in a normal command line project, not in an iOS project since gnu prolog doesn't support arm architecture.